# Sum with conditions jasper studio

Tags: jasper-reports

It is necessary to summarize the field $F{energy} wit conditions $F{type_energy} like "Active Energy".

I try with this(define Variable Sum) , with conditions in Variable Expression:

1. `$F{type_energy} == ("Active Energy")? $F{energy}: new Double(0)`
2. `Boolean.valueOf($F{vrsta_energije}=="Active energy")?$F{iznos_naknade_km}.doubleValue():new Double(0)`
3. `new Double($F{vrsta_energije}!= null && $F{vrsta_energije}.equals("Active energy")?$F{kolicina_vrsna_snaga}.doubleValue():0)`
4. `IF($F{type_energy} == ("Active Energy"), $F{energy}, null)`

   where type of fild is:

   $F{type_energy}    **java.lang.String** 
   and $F{energy}    **java.math.BigDecimal**

Keep getting highscore **0.0** or **null**

Answer (score 1):

change data type of $F{energy} to double in feild expression.
Define a variable sum ($V{Sum}).
keep calculationFunction to none.
Initial value expression as 0.0.
In variable expression have
("Active Energy").equalEgnoreCase( $F{type_energy} ) ? $V{Sum}+$F{energy}: $V{Sum}

Comment: Thank you! 
BUT still have the same problem and I do not find a solution. Still not getting a sum.
I changed fild and condition: 
*$F{type_energy}.contentEquals ("Active Energy ")? $V{Sum}.doubleValue() + $F {energy}.doubleValue()): $V{Sum}.doubleValue()*, because otherwise get error

I try with this: 
**1. $F{type_energy}==("Active Energy")? $V{Sum}.doubleValue() + $F {energy}.doubleValue()): $V{Sum}.doubleValue()**
**2.IF($F{type_energy}==("Active Energy"),$F {energy}.doubleValue()), null)**
 and a steel get a 0.0

Comment: Hi please try the previous solution given by me again,but  try with "equalIgnoreCase". It works fine for me.

Comment: It seems that the problem was in recognition of the string, to identify spacing between words
So I use function: **contentEquals()**. Conditional is: 
$F{type_energy} .contentEquals ("Active Energy") ? $V{Sum}.doubleValue() + $ F {energy}.doubleValue (): $V{Sum}.doubleValue() !
This is work!!
**THANK YOU**